# ConEmu: how do I delete items from the "Create new console" dropdown?

Tags: conemu

In [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/)'s "Create new console" menu, is there a way of deleting items from the list of previously run commands?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open a *Create new console* dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> hotkey can be changed in *Settings* > *Keys*)
2. Right-click on the *Create new console* dialog caption or hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.
3. Menu item > *Reset command history...*

Alternatively, you may edit history manually in registry (HKCU\Software\ConEmu\«ConfigName»\CmdLineHistory) or in ConEmu.xml, whatever you use.

PS. wow, new tag

Comment: Alt-Space may be not working for system menu. There is an option to send this combo to console. Alternatively - Win-Alt-Space must works.

Comment: One more thing - there is key combo for this Create new console dialog )

Comment: Sorry for deludion this morning ) Win+Alt+Space - hotkey for ConEmu system menu. In the dialog - Alt+Space of course. Win+Shift+Space is preferred for opening dialog, because "Create confirmation" option may be Off. Even this option is Off, you can still open dialog from System Menu > New Console with Shift key depressed.

Comment: How that looking now?